# Can not record sound when using pyaudio on raspberry

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, sound-card

I'm using a USB microphone on raspberry3B+, and using pyaudio to record the sound.Today my codes suddenly failed, i'm quiet sure i didn't do anything to my code and i don't think it's a code problem for it was doing really well before(yes, yesterday sound can be recorded), i only made some exchange on SPI settings, or reboot the raspberry.I'm quiet confused, and many of my classmates came across the same problem, they resolved it by reinstalling OS, my deadline is coming, it would be good if there is another way